# how to refer to a modified version of an object (e.g. a subset of a list) from another object without modifying and making a copy of it

Tags: python, object, reference, subset

My goal is to create a new object `myobj2` by performing some operation (e.g. to sum a number to each  element of a list) on a modified version of the input object  (e.g. the subselection of elements of a list ) without altering the original object but retaining the  information that will always let the new object refer back to the original object in the modified version, but without copying the whole original object in to the new one. I'll make a concrete example to make this understandable.

Say the instance `myobj` of the class `Mydata` is a big dataset (in the example it contains a list in the attribute `.data`)

The class `Sum_number` creates an object in which the `.data` attribute contains a list in which each element is the sum of an element of the list in `myobj.data` and a given number.

```
myobj2 = Sum_number (myobj, 1)
```

The attribute `.inputdata` of `myobj2`  contains a reference to the original input object `myobj`.

If I modify `myobj2.inputdata` I also modify `myobj`, trivially.

The class `Sum_number2` instead makes a deep copy of the input data and then picks a subset of the list included in the `.data` attribute given some indexes. Then it performs the sum operation on the selected items.

I wonder if there is a way to do this without having to copy the original object, but in a way that every reference to the original object in the future will always take the modified version.

any stylistic or structural suggestion is welcome too!

```
import copy

class Mydata (object):
    def __init__ (self, mydata):
        self.data = mydata

class Sum_number (object):
    def __init__ (self, inputdata, number):
        self.data = [x + number for x in inputdata.data]
        self.inputdata = inputdata

class Sum_number2 (object):
    def __init__ (self, inputdata, number, selection):

        self.inputdata = copy.deepcopy(inputdata)
        self.data = self.inputdata.data
        self.data = [self.data[i] for  i in selection]
        self.data = [x + number for x in self.data]

myobj = Mydata([1,2,3,4,5])
myobj2 = Sum_number (myobj, 1)
myobj3 = Sum_number2 (myobj, 1, (1,2,3))
```